# Using the id for if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the correct way of addressing the id of an element in an if statement condition?

```
if($('id').val() == Reset)
 var Submit_Status = $("#Reset").val();
else
 var Submit_Status = $("#Nb_var97").val();
```

Thanks,
Neil P.

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML?

Comment: Same as normal selector with the #

Comment: I tried doing the following, this did not work? $(function() {//Open function
$("input").click (function(){ //Open select

if($("input").attr("id") == "Reset")
 var Submit_Status = $("#Reset").val();
else
 var Submit_Status = $("#Nb_var97").val();

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't see your HTML I'm going to post a simple example:

```
<div id="myID"></div>

if($("div").attr("id") == "myID")
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Given your example this would only return the ID of the first element in the $("div") collection. If you had two divs with different IDs, you wouldn't be checking against any but the first.

Comment: Well, ID's are intended to be globally unique so it shouldn't be an issue, assuming use of accepted conventions.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('someSelector').attr('id') == 'Reset')
 var Submit_Status = $("#Reset").val();
else
 var Submit_Status = $("#Nb_var97").val();
```

Comment: an element would have id="element" and a separate id attribute?

Comment: See my comment to another question. This solution would also only check the ID of the first element in the collection.

Comment: The id of the element would be unique, but your selector could be selecting all divs and then only checking the first div's id. Why select a bunch of elements if you're only checking the first one?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('div').attr('id') == 'Reset' ) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check the value of the ID property then you can get it using the `attr` method.

For example, if you were looping through all of the elements with the class `foo` and wanted to check for the id `bar` you could do this in your loops:

```
...
var id = item.attr("id");

if(id == 'bar')
{

}
```

Here's an example where all divs on the page are selected and each one has it's ID checked in turn:

```
var divs = $('div');

divs.each(function(index, value) {
   var id = $(value).attr('id');

    if(id == 'foo')
    {
        // Do foo work
    }
    else if(id == 'bar')
    {
        // Do bar work
    }
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gZHMD/1/

Answer (score 0):

Using a short form ([ternary/conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)) instead of `if`

```
// element could be any html element but inputs have val and div, spans and suchlike don't have val
var Submit_Status = $('element').attr('id') == 'Reset' ? $("#Reset").val() : $("#Nb_var97").val();
```

Also, if you have multiple elements, then you have to select specific one, [an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/gZHMD/3/).