# Passing id attribute in if else statement

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do if else condition that call out the id in the html. I display a small snippet of my code, but the result doesn't come out accordingly to the condition given. It only display the the last alert('*New Passwords do not match').

I have google on regarding this. The closes I can find is [Using the id for if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304343/using-the-id-for-if-condition), however this only can be done by passing id in the 'div' element.

Is there any other ways to do something quite similar to my code? I know my syntax is not 100% correct, that's why I need an expert advice. Thank you for your time in advance

**Here is the if else statement**

```
   if( $('new_pwd').attr('id')  === "") {
            alert('*New Password Empty');
    } else if ( $('retype_pwd').attr('id') === "") {
            alert('*Retype Password Empty');
    } else if( $('new_pwd').attr('id') != $('retype_pwd').attr('id')) {
            alert('*New Passwords do not match') ;
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>New Password</td>
      <td><input id="new_pwd" type="password" name="new_password"></input></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Retype Password</td>
      <td><input id="retype_pwd" type="password" name="retype_password"></input></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're selecting an element by its `id` (or at least *intending* to), and then comparing the `id` of the element you selected (*by its `id`*) against a string? Why not just test the `length` of the element you selected (or tried to select)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `#` to call-out an id in a selector, such as $('#new_pwd'). Basically, the jquery selector works similar to CSS where you use `#` to refer to ids of elements, `.` for classes, and pure text will attempt to match DOM elements, like $('table tr td').

For full documentation, see http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/.

EDIT: You also have to use `val()` to get the value of the input field. For your code, the following should work:

```
if( $('#new_pwd').val() === "") {
        alert('*New Password Empty');
} else if ( $('#retype_pwd').val() === "") {
        alert('*Retype Password Empty');
} else if( $('#new_pwd').val() !== $('#retype_pwd').val()) {
        alert('*New Passwords do not match') ;
};
```

For more on `val`: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Thanks @Jason W That works. I did the # before this, but didn't put the val(). No wonder it won't works. That did trick!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but too select an element by its id, you need a hash sign before it. So `$('#retype_pwd')` selects the element whose id is 'retype_pwd'.

By leaving the hash sign out, you are trying to select *that kind of element*. i.e. `$('div')` selects all `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the # for the div selector, and you are compairing the id's of your divs, you should compare the value of the input.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s7vjzqcj/)

**jQuery:**

```
$('#click').click(function() {
if( $('#new_pwd').val()  === "") {
            alert('*New Password Empty');
    } else if ( $('#retype_pwd').val() === "") {
            alert('*Retype Password Empty');
    } else if( $('#new_pwd').val() != $('#retype_pwd').val()) {
            alert('*New Passwords do not match') ;
    };      
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>New Password</td>
      <td><input id="new_pwd" type="password" name="new_password"></input></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Retype Password</td>
      <td><input id="retype_pwd" type="password" name="retype_password"></input></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<button id = "click" >click</button>
```

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
if( $('#new_pwd').val()  === "") {
            alert('*New Password Empty');
    } else if ( $('#retype_pwd').val() === "") {
            alert('*Retype Password Empty');
    } else if( $('#new_pwd').val() != $('#retype_pwd').val()) {
            alert('*New Passwords do not match') ;
    };      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>New Password</td>
      <td><input id="new_pwd" type="password" name="new_password"></input></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Retype Password</td>
      <td><input id="retype_pwd" type="password" name="retype_password"></input></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<button id = "click" >click</button>
```